Playwright authentication state gives me a cookies empty array
I have used Playwright to enable the authentication state (shared account in all tests) but I got this result:
{
  "cookies": [],
  "origins": [
    {
      "origin": "http://localhost:3000",
      "localStorage": [
        {
          "name": "locale",
          "value": "en_US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

where the cookies array is empty, so my other tests based on authentication do not work.
I use:
"@playwright/test": "^1.45.1",

Here the playwright config:
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from "path";

// Read from ".env" file.
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, ".env") });

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: 'html',
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    // baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'setup',
      testMatch: 'tests/auth-setup.ts',
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        storageState: 'playwright/.auth/user.json',
       },
       dependencies: ['setup'],
    },

    // {
    //   name: 'firefox',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    // },

    // {
    //   name: 'webkit',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
    // },

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
    //   use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
    // },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Edge'], channel: 'msedge' },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Google Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], channel: 'chrome' },
    // },
  ],

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  // webServer: {
  //   command: 'npm run start',
  //   url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  //   reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  // },
});

Here the setup script:
import { test as setup, expect, chromium, Browser, Page } from '@playwright/test';

const authFile = 'playwright/.auth/user.json';

setup('authenticate user', async ({ }) => {
  const browser: Browser = await chromium.launch({headless: true});
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page: Page = await context.newPage();

  await page.goto(`${process.env.APP_BASE_URL}/login`);
  await page.locator('input[name="username"]').fill(`${process.env.APP_USERNAME}`);
  await page.locator('input[name="password"]').fill(`${process.env.APP_PASSWORD}`);
  await page.locator("button[aria-label='confirmButton']").click();

  await page.waitForURL(`${process.env.APP_BASE_URL}/accounts#operations`);

  await expect(page.getByText('Available balance')).toHaveText('Available balance');

  await page.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
});

Here the test:
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('display accounts page', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(`${process.env.APP_BASE_URL}/accounts#operations`);
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
  await expect(page.getByText('Available balance')).toHaveText('Available balance');
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
  await page.screenshot({
    path: "./playwright/screenshots/screen-capture.png",
  });
});

The screen-capture.png file has captured the login page.
I see that the authentication setup is green and my other test is red.

Note: I have also followed this video Playwright Authentication: Shared Account in All Tests and I got information in the "cookies" property and others tests worked correctly.
Do you know in what cases the "cookies" property can be empty?

Can you post your config and Playwright version? Preferably a simple relevant backend that reproduces the auth problem, so the example is runnable. Other than the no-no await page.waitForTimeout(5000); everything looks fine in the code on a spot check.

I have added the config and Playwright version @ggorlen

In your setup script, it should be setup not test. Can you try to rewrite the setup file described in the documentation? It should work.

@alfah "setup" is just an alias for test; import { test as setup } from '@playwright/test'

@alfah Yes, it is just an alias. I have updated the code, and I have an empty cookies array. I have added an image to show that the authentication setup (test) works but not the other test because the auth state (cookies) is not saved.
